# CodeCogs Latex Editor not working properly with multiple instances of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am working on a Rails project where I am using [Equation Editor plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/eqneditor) in `CKEditor` for displaying editors in `text-areas`

The [CodeCogs Latex Editor](http://ckeditor.com/addon/eqneditor) is working properly if the `view` contain only one CKEditor instance. When multiple instances occur in the same `view` the equation editor is not working properly.

I found a similar issue raised [here](http://www.codecogs.com/pages/forums/pagegen.php?id=2833). But solution given there is not working.

**Update**

This is the error that I get on the browser console:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor_embedded_json.php?id=CCtoolbar1&SID=&design=efull". eq_editor-lite-17.js:1
```

Comment: do you find solution

Comment: @GiteshPurbia : No, I was not able to fix this issue.

Comment: having save issue here. looking for new mathematical plugin